# Nested synchronized blocks in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, thread-safety, synchronized-block

I read code somewhere in which multiple identical synchronized blocks are used, like this:

```
@implementation Test {
  NSObject var;
}

- (void)method1 {
  @synchronized(self) {
    @synchronized(var) {
     ...
    }
  }
}

- (void)method2 {
  @synchronized(self) {
    @synchronized(var) {
     ...
    }
  }
}
```

What's the rationale behind doing nested synchronized of self and var this way? Isn't @synchronized on var alone enough?

Comment: Is `var` an instance variable, a global, or two separate local variables?

Comment: var is an instance variable.  Edited example.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not.  Without *a lot* more context it's hard to tell.  (But you're getting into some dangerous territory.)